# FindRoot options

Tags: equation-solving

I found an example of `FindRoot` usage that I couldn't find documented.
It looks like:

```
FindRoot[f[x] == 0.4, {x, 0, 1, 0, 1}]
```

The documentation shows this case `FindRoot[lhs==rhs, {x, xstart, xmin, xmax}]` searches for a solution, stopping the search if x ever gets outside the range.  But the example I found has an extra argument.  What does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: I put `True` in that position and got the error *FindRoot::bbound: Search region bound True for variable number 1 is not a number or Infinity. >>* so my guess is search region bound. `FindRoot[Cos[x] == 0.4, {x, 0, 1, 0, 3}]` finds the solution $x \approx 1.59$. Another odd thing `FindRoot[Cos[x] == 0.4, {x, 0, 1, 0, 0.5}]` *FindRoot::streg: The starting point {1.} is not in the search region {{0.},{0.5}}. >>*

Comment: I think the 4 values are : 2 starting points and the search region; 2 starting points are used by the "Secant" method for instance. For instance try `FindRoot[x^2 - 2 == 0, {x, 1.1, 1.9, 1.2, 2}, Method -> "Secant"]` and move around the 1.1 or the 1.9.

Comment: @b.gatessucks that agrees with my last error.

Answer (score 11):

As suggested by **b.gatessucks**, the 4 values are the two starting points used by the "Secant" method for instance and the search region.
In fact if you use

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, x_a, x_b, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

you get always the same result as for

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, x_a, x_b}],
```

whilst if you take

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, x_a, x_b, -y, y}]
```

with `x_a` or `x_b` bigger than `y` in modulus you'll get the error

```
FindRoot::streg: "The starting point is not in the search region"
```